# How to specify minimum required version for application in msbuild cmd

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

When we publish application from visual studio publish option using clickonce, there is option to add "Minimum required version" as below.

[image]

I am publishing my application using msbuild command and I want to pass "Minimum Required Version" to command. I tried to find out for this, but couldn't get any option to pass.

One possible way is to add this value in csproj file as below

[image]

But I want to pass to msbuild command.
I am referring [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022#build-net-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line) article for msbuild commands

How can I pass minimum required version to msbuild command?

Comment: Please paste code where possible, not screenshots, people cannot copy text from screenshots. Anyway: does `msbuild /p:MinimumRequiredVersion=xxx` not work? Property values specified on the commandline normally override what is in the project file.

Comment: no, specifying just MinimumRequiredVersion will not work, we need to add one more parameter - UpdateRequired=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out this problem

To add minimum required version, we need to mention `MinimumRequiredVersion=xxxx` along with `UpdateRequired=true`

so final command would be as below

```
msbuild /target:publish /p:Configuration="testing";ApplicationVersion=1.0.0.*;ApplicationRevision=4;UpdateRequired=true;MinimumVersionRequired=1.0.0.4;publishDir=\\publishingDirectory
```

Note: ApplicationVersion and MinumumVersionRequired should match.